Do "halves" of open sets exist in locally convex vector spaces?
Let $V$ be a locally convex Hausdorff topological vector space (over $\mathbb{R}$) and let $U\subseteq V$ be an open neighbourhood of the origin. Does there always exist another open neighbourhood $U'$ of the origin such that $U'+U'\subseteq U$?
In normed spaces this is clear because we can just take $U'=\frac{1}{2}B$ where $B$ is some open ball around the origin that is contained in $U$.

Hint.  Use the fact that addition is continuous.

This is true in any topological vector space:

Given any open neighborhood $U$ of the origin there exists an open neighborhood $W$ of the origin such that
$$ W \subset \overline {W} \subset W+ W \subset U .$$
In particular, every TVS is regular.

You should be able to find this result in any book that deals with TVS. If not, I can provide a proof.
